# Given a geometric series, $a2^n$, is there a concise formula for finding the first term greater than or equal to m (a, n & m are natural)?

Tags: number-theory

Given a geometric series, $a2^n$, is there a concise formula for finding the first term greater than or equal to $m$ ($a$, $n$ and $m$ are natural numbers)?

Having some computer programming experience, I could easily compute it, but was wondering if someone might know of a more straightforward mathematical solution.

Comment: $n \geqslant \frac{\log m - \log a}{\log 2}$?

Comment: Thanks, Daniel, i seem to have forgotten my elementary schooling...

Comment: @DanielFischer got number theory? ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18790284/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-coprime-subsets-of-the-set-1-2-3-n/19067700#19067700

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $\;k-$th element in the geometric progression $\,\{a2^n\}\;$ is given by

$$a_k=a2^{k-1}\stackrel ?\ge m\stackrel{\text{assuming}\;a>0}\iff2^{k-1}\ge\frac ma\iff k-1\ge\frac{\log\frac ma}{\log2}\iff$$

$$\iff k\ge\frac{\log  2+\log m-\log a}{\log 2}$$

with $\;\log\;$   in any (legal) basis.

Comment: Thank you, it seems quite simple now that you remind me of my elementary school math, ha.